# Magento products not showing after uploading images

Tags: php, image, magento, product

I'm facing a really strange problem. I wrote a custom product importer, based on different other importers. The importer is working fine.

I can import the products and they are showing up on the Front-End and Back-End. But after the importer adds images to the products, the products are suddenly not showing up anymore in the Front-End. All the lists with products are empty if it expects products with images.

Of course I refreshed all the cache and indexes.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** :

Fixed it with installing php5-gd, found the solution on http://codepoets.co.uk/2011/magento-not-finding-product-images-solution/

Comment: Have you checked your product's visibility?

Comment: Yeah i did that. They are showing first up until i add the images to the products

Comment: Clear the cache and check it once. and also check the product stock availability.

Comment: Whether the products are present in Back end...?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I fixed it with installing php5-gd. With the tips on this site http://codepoets.co.uk/2011/magento-not-finding-product-images-solution/